# ubuntu 18.10 optimus dual boot hang on first boot (Dell 7567 )

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia-optimus

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10 (Desktop install) and when I rebooted got a blue screen which I think was something to do with UDIF, was up for 5 secs or so and never came back, not sure if this is relevant.

Then when I boot and chose Ubuntu I get the boot screen (Ubuntu with dots under it) then the screen clears and I just get a mouse pointer.  Basically, the system is frozen.

Not sure what to go now.  Did a load of googling and still not sure.

Comment: First steps I would do was validate your ISO download, then validate your install media, as even a single-bit error may not show during install, but can create a corrupted install you only notice on first or subsequent boot. These issues are easy & quick to do pre-install but are very slow & tedious to diagnose post-install. You may already have done this, but if you hadn't these would be my first steps (usually done pre-install, but always first step on a failed install if they were skipped).  *I could provide links for both, but you may already have done it and just not said*

Comment: I actually have downloaded the ISO twice and diff shows they are not identical.  Also 'sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS' gives me 'ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso: OK'.  is that what you mean?

Comment: For step 1 (download) YEP.  But that doesn't confirm the write to thumb-drive was perfect, which I've found more problematic myself. The screens/keys needed for this vary on language, on release & which ISO media you downloaded - but the wiki documentation is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  (*where media is referred to as CD (it still is) & the screen images won't be the same; there's a better wiki page for it but hopefully that's enough for you*).