# Create ISO from Linux image with verify

Tags: system-installation, 18.10

Ive been having problems doing a Ubuntu install ([ubuntu 18.10 optimus dual boot hang on first boot (Dell 7567 )](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131987/ubuntu-18-10-optimus-dual-boot-hang-on-first-boot-dell-7567)) and think it may be the USB stick was not written properly.  How can I write and verify the image (was using windows to do this but do have another Linux box I can use to make the USB). I know there is a verify in the installation menu but would rather do it manualy (i.e. with CLI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose USB has a file `md5sum.txt`

1. Plug in the USB drive in any Linux OS.
2. CD to USB drive

   ```
   cd /media/$USER/<drive name>
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   md5sum -c md5sum.txt | grep -v OK || echo "All OK"
   ```

   If there is a defect, output is something like

   ```
   md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
   ```

   If not

   ```
   All OK
   ```

   No output means all OK.

   For full report run

   ```
   md5sum -c md5sum.txt
   ```

Comment: So this means that is is both downloaded and copied to USB without errors?

Comment: Yes it does mean that.